# XPath 'or' operator using the 'pipe' character?

Tags: xml, xpath, operators, msxml6

Within an AutoHotKey routine I'm using MSXML6 to parse an XML document.

```
doc := ComObjCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")
doc.async := false
doc.loadXML(xmldata)
doc.selectNodes("osm/way|rel[tag[@k='railway'][@v='station']]").length
```

In the `SelectNodes` line I wish to filter the results to only two nodes: `way|rel`

It doesn't throw an error but ignores `rel` returning only `way` nodes.

This syntax works when using it in Saxon. Is there a solution to this in MSXML, or is there an alternative parser I could implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath 2.0 is required to use the `|` within a single XPath like that. MSXML supports only XPath 1.0.

### XPath 1.0

@wp78de's answer works (+1), but you can avoid having to duplicate the `tag[@k='railway'][@v='station']` condition across `|` by using the `self::` axis within the predicate :

```
osm/*[(self::way or self::rel) and tag[@k='railway'][@v='station']]
```

### XPath 2.0

For the benefit of later readers who might be using a XPath 2.0 library:

```
osm/(way|rel)[tag[@k='railway' and @v='station']]
```

(@wp78de had posted this too prior to realizing that OP was limited to XPath 1.0.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify what the asterisk (presumably meaning 'all') is for in this instance?

Comment: `*` here matches any element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MSXML (v6) you are limited to the features of XML 1.0 ([as defined by the W3C as of v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753751(v=vs.85))). This means you are not allowed to use alternations on an axis step ([ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)). Therefore, you need to split your path:

```
doc.selectNodes("osm/way[tag[@k='railway'][@v='station']] | osm/rel[tag[@k='railway'][@v='station']]")
```

I've tested this end-to-end in PowerShell using MSXML6 via COM and it is working as expected.

Comment: Works (+1) but can be [simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545705/290085).